# What is this small cubic device in my recessed light housing?

Tags: light-fixture

I just replaced the light bulb in the recessed light and it is working.

I noticed this strange object.

[image: object]

What is it ?

Comment: Temperature sensor/fuse(?)  What type of light bulb is it for?

Comment: @crip659 so once it triggers does it reset or needs to be replaced ?

Comment: Unknown, some do some need replacement.  Could be something also.

Comment: @crip659 make that an answer and I will give you the well deserved credit. I do not need to know about UAL and Underwriters, just it is a thermal protection switch.

Comment: I was just guessing, @Gil gave a much better answer, including why it had to be there, which I did not know.

Comment: I liked your guess better than lecture on Underwriters rules electrician refusal and so on. Just simple and clean answer I was looking for, it is a thermal protection. Go do it

Answer (score 10):

That thermal device is a a requirement, for the recessed fixture to have  Underwriters Laboratory approval. Without that approval, qualified electricians will not install them. UL states for approval a recessed fixture must have a thermal protection device built into them. I have seen two types, thermal fuses which when blow needs to be replaced or the fixture replaced. The other which most recessed fixtures have is like a thermal disk on an electric heating appliance, it snaps open then when it cools down it snaps closed. I do not know what the trip temperature is but the manufacturer determined if it gets hotter then this device the fixture becomes unsafe and a potential fire hazard. I believe this type of protection is required in all appliances etc that get hot such as coffee makers.

Comment: It does not look like it is easy to replace, so hopefully it resets.

Comment: You can take a blow dryer with the heat off and cool it that way to force it to reset but I would expect by now it has cooled. Try a smaller lamp.

Comment: OP said the light works, just did not know what the little box was for.